# How to deserialize ProtoBuf-net in Android

Tags: java, android, protobuf-net

I have a WebApi that uses ProtoBuf-net for its serialization. It works fine.

Now, I need to use the WebApi in my Android app. My question is, how to use deserialize it in Android? Or it is **not** possible and I must use Google.ProtoBuf in my WebApi?

I really like ProtoBuf-net, so, if I could, I would love to keep using ProtoBuf-net. I just need to find away to deserialize it in Android. Please point me to a right direction.

Thanks...

### UPDATE:

Here is the response when getting from Fiddler

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcWENJRllcRG90TkVUXFVCcm9kXFVXZWJBUElcVVdlYkFQSVxhcGlcZGV2aWNlXEdldEdyb3Vwcw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 07:36:52 GMT
Content-Length: 76


"   XzFood          !        
&   XzClothing          !
```

Here is my model

```
private int id = 0;
[ProtoMember(11)]
public int Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
}

private string name = string.Empty;
[ProtoMember(15)]
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}

private List<CDProduct> products = new List<CDProduct>();
[ProtoMember(45)]
public List<CDProduct> Products
{
    get { return products; }
    set { products = value; }
}
```

Comment: how does the serialized data look like?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was in the meeting all day. I'll update my question now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention Android, and you mention Java. If you're coding in Java on Android, then indeed you won't be able to use protobuf-net, since that is .NET-specific - but protobuf-net tries to make it easy for you to transition. In your existing code, you can use:

```
var proto = Serializer.GetProto<YourRootType>();
```

which will give you a `.proto` schema that represents the model of `YourRootType` (there are options for "proto2" vs "proto3", etc). It *usually* works fine, but if you have things like `DateTime` and *aren't* using the `DataFormat.WellKnown` option, then it can get a bit awkward (tip: if possible, switch to the `DataFormat.WellKnown` option for any `DateTime`/`TimeStamp` properties, but note that doing so is a breaking change; this will use the `google.protobuf.Timestamp` and `google.protobuf.Duration` layouts added by Google in the "proto3" timeframe).

You then run that .proto schema through `protoc`, and you *should* get usable Java code for the same model.

Note: feel free to change the names in the generated .proto schema if you want to tweak it; names don't matter - field numbers and types, however: do.

Comment: would you ever consider to do protobuf-android? I really love protobuf-net. And, mate, you are **my hero**! In regards to Time, I normally convert it do double (and I used milliseconds passed since `01/01/2015 00:00:00`), so time is not an issue. Is there a way I can use deserialize it manually (ie. write my own code)? I want to get away from .proto schema if possible. That is because if I change my model, I need to regenerate the proto schema, then use protoc to get java code then put it in my android. I rather change my android class directly (if possible).

Comment: @Sam in that case you're probably looking for [`protostuff`](https://protostuff.github.io/docs/protostuff-runtime/). As for me and Java: quite simply, I lack the experience in Java to do a good job at that; that *may* change, but ... it isn't something I've been looking to do. I'd rather be *really deep* in one thing than *moderately deep* in several